# Socket.io emit in Android not working

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to connect with socket.io in my android app, but emit don't working (from js client everything works perfect). 
Here is my code

```
try {
            IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
            opts.query = "token=" + PreferenceManager.getToken(CreateOrder.this);

            socket = IO.socket(Constants.sBaseUrl + "socket.io/", opts);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        socket.on("connect", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                socket.emit("order", "something");
                socket.disconnect();
            }
        });

        socket.connect();
```

Can you help me ? Thanks ! and sorry for my English :)

Comment: "not working" is an unacceptable description of the problem. From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "...Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: @James K Polk dear friend, I try a lot of debugging, a lot of variations and waste a lot of time ! If you can, please help me, if you can't or need more information, please ask me. I read about the article that you included, but in community i didn't find answer, otherwise i will not publish the question.

Comment: Do you have internet permission in manifest? 

As well, you emit 'order' only when you receive a 'connect' message. That's not needed.

Try to move the 
socket.emit("order", "something"); after socket.connect();

Comment: @JamesKPolk I wanna now, maybe i do something wrong, because in [official webiste](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) example the same that in my code.

Comment: @AdrianComan Hello my dear friend ! in manifest, yes i have the internet permission (i do a lot of stuff, before socket connection(register user, finding location etc)). I try to move socket.emit() after socket.connect(); (At first it was so), but it still do nothing :(

Comment: Maybe there is the version problem ? I am using io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3